# How to set system app is not disabled?

Tags: android, system

How can I set a system app (my custom system app) to be NOT DISABLED? 
Just like the Launcher or Settings that the "Disable" button is not enabled. So the user can't disable my system app.

Below is the Launcher's effect:

[image: Launcher's effect]

Comment: Why would you want your app to be not disabled? Let the user decide that for themselves! You should not be preventing the user from disabling it, from where I can see, as that is your app.... just saying

Comment: I think you need to provide a bit more info, such as what the app does, as you say its a system app you developed, and is baked into the  ROM from scratch, i.e. you rolled your own rom with the app in place? Cannot answer for definite... :)

Comment: It is unlikely that this has anything to do with programming, and more likely that it has to do with some system database on the ROM which hosts your app.

Comment: I am developing a widget app for ROM, and when I disable it, it will become a DEAD one and can't get alive even I ENABLE it. So I want to DISABLE the "Disable" button. Maybe it is a bug that widget can not be     reset after Enable it. Thanks!

Comment: @herbertD did you find a way to do that?

Comment: @Singh, it is been a long time, and I don't remember. sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible for a third party application (like yours) to define itself as not being possible to disable-  It's important that the user be able to disable *any* application on their system.  If you find a way, that will be considered a security flaw, and it'll likely be disabled in the next release of Android :)

Launcher and Settings are special cases in terms of not being possible to disable, since disabling those would make it difficult/impossible for the user to maintain their own device (or to undo their decision, since they wouldn't be able to launch the settings Activity and re-enable it).

Comment: I am developing a widget for my ROM, not a 3rd party app. Thanks!